# Can't close Ionic-super-popup when it's inside a modal

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When I open a modal and show a validation message, I can't close the message, but I can close the modal, but can't close the message..

[Plugin ionic-super-popup](https://github.com/garrettmac/ionic-super-popup)

Modal code

```
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modalCadastrar', {
            scope: scope,
            backdropClickToClose: false
        }).then(function (modal) {
            scope.modalCadastrar = modal;
        });
```

Message code:

```
ionicSuperPopup.show("Basic Super Popup!");
```

Obs: it's working when it's not inside a modal...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was on plugin github website..

```
$scope.showIonicSuperPopup=function(){ 
//ADD THIS BEFORE
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('workaround-modal.html', {
   scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.workaroundModal = modal;
   $scope.workaroundModal.show();
   $scope.workaroundModal.hide();
});

ionicSuperPopup.show(....);
```

};